# Playing flash (.flv) videos on the web in a way that portable devices can view them

Tags: jquery, flash, html5-video

A friend of mine has created a movie for my site, it's in .flv format. I've heard of the popular flash player called flowplayer, but I have a bad feeling such a player will not work on the ipad and other devices which do not support flash. Is there a way to play a video in the flash format through a non-flash player so that the content can be viewed on all devices?

I'm open to any ideas. Perhaps I may even need to convert the video to another format somehow.

Thanks for any help,

Evan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have already written you cannot use Flash Video on (most) mobile devices as it will require the Flash Player for playing the video. Yet, the actual Flash Movie (`.swf`) won't do much more than open a video file (`.flv` in your case) that it will then play back inside the Flash Container.

To have video ready for all devices you will usually use an approach that will try to serve HTML5 `<video>` first and fall back to Flash when the browser isn't HTML5 ready yet. This is described in the **[html5-video-tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/html5-video/info)**, at **[video for everybody](http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody)** or at **[Dive into HTML5](http://diveintohtml5.info/video.html)**.

Regarding your situation with the single FLV file it depends on which codec that file is encoded in. HTML5 video and Flash Video can share the same source file in case it is using H264 encoding. Files like this are usually called `.m4v`, `.mp4` or `.f4v` though, so I guess your file might still be using the On2VP8-codec used by older versions of Flash.

So you might consider asking your friend what codec that file actually uses and, depending on the outcome, to re-encode that video into a H264 format so you can use it in both Flash- and HTML5-based playback.

Unfortunately this still will not cater for users of Firefox or Opera (also be aware that Chrome might drop H264 support at some time in the future as Google is trying to push the WebM-Codec), so you might have to choose between making these browsers fall back to flash as well or serving another kind of media source (`ogg` probably) for them.

Comment: Thank you for the very useful links. What I've understood from reading them is that the player will, based on the device detected, use either flash or html - that's fine. I'm having trouble finding out what format the video must be in in order to work with this player.

Comment: @Evan it's not a question what the player supports (it will basically just serve the media that the browser requests), but what the browser supports. At the moment the situation looks like you will have to serve `.m4v`,`.webm` and `.ogg` as HTML5 video and a Flash Fallback (either using the `.m4v` or a seperate `.flv`) if you really want to cater for all users.